# Connection ADSL PPPoE + 108M Wireless Access Point TP-Link

Tags: connection, wireless-access-point, pppoe

In Window is simple:
1) I create a a new connection (RDS) as PPPoE and configure with username and password.
2) I have a wireless access point tp-link I plug my cable and my laptop is connected on wireless
3)To make the connection available I simple click on connection RDS (I am connected to wireless) and everything is OK.

How to make this connection work on Ubuntu?
I make a new connection with my username and password and named it RDS and I am connected to my wireless access point but how to make my internet to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't make pppoe connections over wifi using the network manager. They have logged this as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/613679

The work around to make pppoe connections over wifi is shown here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10595616&postcount=7

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If I read you correctly what you require is a RDS client package from the package manager

Comment: Exactly, I have a RDS connection and unable to connect through my Wireless Access Point TP-Link...

Comment: Could you give a specific package name?